# Nightmare doesn't run twice in a row - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, electron, nightmare

**EDIT**

I have noticed the removal of the `.end()` function appears to solve the issue, but after reading the Nightmare docs on the use of `.end()` it says: `Completes any queue operations, disconnect and close the electron process.`

Now while this does solve the problem, am I now just opening more and more electron processes each time the route is called, which will eventually cause the server to run out of memory, or is this a safe way to fix the issue?

**ORIGINAL TEXT**

Please consider the following problem:

I am developing a Node based service that will allow the user to request screenshot of a particular URL.

For this I am using [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) to visit the URL, wait 2 seconds, take a screenshot, which is saved to the disk, convert it to base64, delete the image and then return the base64 string.

```
    console.log('Nightmare starts');

    nightmare
    .goto(url)
    .wait(2000)
    .screenshot(filename)
    .end()
    .then(function (result)
    {
      fs.exists(filename, function(exists) 
      {
          if (exists)
          {
              data = fs.readFileSync(filename);
              var base64 = data.toString('base64')
              fs.unlink(filename);
              var output = {'message':'success','map_image':base64};
              res.send(output);
          }
      });
    })
    .catch(function (error)
    {
      console.error('Search failed:', error);
    });

    console.log("Nightmare Finished");
```

The above code works just fine, the first time it runs. However any subsequent calls to this just consoles "Nightmare starts" and "Nightmare Finished" instantly with the actual code in-between not running. I don't appear to have any errors display, nothing is caught if I wrap it in a try/catch. The node requires a reboot to allow it to happen again.

Something worth noting is that I am running on a headless ubuntu machine, as electron (one of the nightmare dependencies) appears to need a GUI, I am using xvfb to launch the node using the following command:

```
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=1 node server.js
```

I'm assuming this may be an issue with some resource not being released correctly on the first run, but any assistance would be appreciated.

Also open to any constructive criticism of my code, very new to Node and i'm sure i'm not writing in the most optimal way (sync file loading etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are simply misplacing where you are creating the nightmare instances. Cannot help much without some more code snippet and information.

## Way 1

Create nightmare instance every time and close them after you are done with your task. It will require some time to boot up the instance, but it will also lessen the memory load. Not to mention you can have multiple nightmare instances for different users.

## Way 2

Don't end and re-use same nightmare instance. Have multiple nightmare instances and queue the call for screenshot. The websites will load fast and it won't take time to boot up an instance, but you will have longer wait time for longer queue.

Comment: I am now using Way 1 and everything appears to work well, thanks very much for your time.